# How to use table component and pass parameters(Map) or variables as datasource to the table

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have created the table using the table component in ireport 4.5.0.I want to pass data through map in my code.So i gave the datasource through Dataset Run.
   In that i have tried all the way by giving 'Connection/Datasource exp','Parameters' and 'Parameters map exp',but i didnt get the table.
   I am getting just a line not even the empty cell.I created the map parameter in subdataset also and also in table component,i can't guess what step i missed..

**subDataset**

```
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 2">
    <parameter name="Details" class="java.util.Map"/>
</subDataset>
```

**Table Component**

```
  <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="230"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 2">
                    <datasetParameter name="Details">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{Details}.get("Name")]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="25">
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="44" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="25" height="44"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="255">
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="44" rowSpan="1">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="255" height="44"/>
                            <box leftPadding="5"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
                <jr:column width="275">
                    <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="44" rowSpan="1">
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="275" height="44"/>
                            <box leftPadding="5"/>
                            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Details}.get("Name")]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:detailCell>
                </jr:column>
            </jr:table>
        </componentElement>
```

I also tried the dataset Run as

```
           <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 2">
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{Details}.get( "Name" )]]></parametersMapExpression>
                </datasetRun>
```

and

```
    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 2">
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{Details}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                </datasetRun>
```

and

```
        <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 2">
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                </datasetRun>
```

But i got only  a single line as output,How to pass the map to the table,what mistake i made?Help me pls.Thanks..